# Visual Studio Code cant locate my python interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I can run python in the terminal but it shows that the python interpreter is not found and when I run the file it shows `the python path in your debug configuration is invalid`.

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZsDw.png)

when i click on `select python interpreter`, it shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV48U.png), and yes the file path is completely [valid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z3Bc.png)

[python works perfectly fine in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drEZX.png)

Comment: What does your debug configuration look like? Be sure to configure it correctly there too

Answer (score 0):

Try the Python Extension in VS-Code. Go on the left to "Extensions", type "Python", go for the first one or which ever you like (I chose the first). You´ll probably need to select your python interpreter again after this